# Binary file read in c#

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

I want to open a binary data file and read that binary data file and store that in an array.

I open the file using its path and stored those data's using readalllines. Those datas are showing as unknown.

Can you please help regarding this.

Comment: It's going to very difficult to answer your question properly without your code. Please can you supply a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code and full details of your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly the use of the [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1) method, *which only works on text files, not binary files.*

Try using [ReadAllBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netcore-3.1) instead.